# How do I use relative paths from a pre-made index.html template and css in a Django app?

Tags: html, css, django-templates, django-views, relative-path

I am using a pre-made bootstrap index.html and css sheets.  In the previous folder structure, the index.html and all accompanying folders like css, js, fonts, img, etc... were all in one folder.  Now they are in two places as shown below.  When I open the index page as an app from the local Django development webserver, it loads the index fine, but all the relative links on the page are broken - css, js, img, etc...

I am new to Django.

Previous bootstrap folder structure:

```
      - public_web_site
         - bootstrap_1
             - css
             - fonts
             - img
             - js
             - index.html
```

I would like the Django project organized as follows:

```
- myproject
  - polls
  - myproject_django
  - public_web_site
     - static
          - public_web_site
             - bootstrap_1
                 - css
                 - fonts
                 - img
                 - js
          - admin
      - templates
          - public_web_site
             - index.html
          - admin           
      - admin.py
      - apps.py
      - models.py
      - urls.py
      - views.py
```

This works:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'public_web_site/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

However this does not:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">    

Not Found: /pub_boots/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

To re-state the problem:  Is there someplace I can add a variable or a path name to allow a pre-made template to function without requiring me to edit every relative link to use Django {% static %} paths?  Or is there a simpler/better way to just drop a pre-made bootstrap website into a Django app?

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the preceding "/" to a path in HTML, it looks for the file starting from the current URL. Example:

If you call "css/bootstrap.min.css" from "http://www.example.com/some-directory/somepage.html"

The browser will request: http://www.example.com/some-directory/css/bootstrap.min.css

You didn't post the referrer URL, so might want to check that. I always use absolute paths to be safe, especially since I use mod-rewrite.

Comment: I think the referrer URL is different in the two cases  - one uses the Django {% static %} variable, the other is plain html.  And since the basic folder structure has changed (index used to be in a folder with img,js,css folders) now the html paths don't work.  I'm asking if there's an easy way to add that new path so I don't have to change all the links.  Your answer inspired a possible work around - could move the index.html. but that breaks the template engine in Django I think :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the question with your good point about the relative URLs - hopefully a little more clear.

Comment: Perhaps create symbolic links to the asset directories? Of course, this would require shell access to your hosting server!